# Question closed by votes from people who do not appear to be familiar with the topic

Tags: feature-request, tags, vote-to-close, closed-questions

This question was closed by five votes: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24631551/1

It is true that the question was poorly written.  It seems likely that English was not the author's first language.

But what concerns me is that the close votes came from five people who do not appear to have a strong interest in iOS, XCode, or the like.  When I look at the tags of the people who made the close votes, I see Java, Javascript, Android, Linux, Visual Studio, php, and so forth.  But not one of the close voters had any iOS-related tags in the list of top tags on their profile page.

I think this is a problem.  A question should be closed if it is not helpful to the audience of people who would be interested in it.  In this case, that's people who know iOS programming.

As a comment noted, the question was entirely clear to iOS programmers, notwithstanding the poor wording.  That should be the standard for closing or not.  Whether or not it makes sense to other stripes of programmers should be irrelevant.

I don't know what is the right way to tweak the system to keep this kind of thing from happening.  But I do think the system needs a tweak.

Comment: This stuff happens all the time.  Vote to reopen; it's all you can do.

Comment: Ugh, the question asks for links.  Off topic.

Comment: The original question is +22-7 now and it's essentially the same as the very first version. The closers were too fast and too clueless, again... and I think it's a real problem.

Answer (score 19):

The right way is simple: edit the question. Nobody needs technical knowledge to know a question is hard to understand: all they need to do is have trouble understanding it. This is not a flaw to be fixed. They were right to close it. **But closing is not permanent** and all it's waiting for is someone -you!- to fix it.

Thanks to your familiarity with the technical details you know what the asker is asking. Great. Make the question better, and it will be reopened (taken off hold.) This is what closing is for - to call a pause while a question is fixed. As someone who understands it you're in the perfect position to fix it. Your edit will automatically queue the question for reopening, too.

Comment: Closing may not be permanent, but some site are fast on deleting the question.